# url extracted from Beautiful Soup from href Tag is not recognized by urllib2

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, href, urllib2

I am learning Python and Beautiful Soup and as an exercise I webscrape a testing webpage.  My objective is to extract a url from the webpage and then follow this url to extract another url.

My code is the following:

First step:

```
path = "http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Fikret.html"
pattern = re.compile(r'"(.+)"')
page = urllib2.urlopen(path)
soup = bs(page, 'lxml')
a = soup.find_all("a")
path = re.search(pattern, str(a[2])).group(0)
path
```

Out:

```
'"http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Montgomery.html"'
```

Second step:

```
page = urllib2.urlopen(path)
soup = bs(page, 'lxml')
a = soup.find_all("a")
path = re.search(pattern, str(a[2])).group(0)
path
```

Out:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-14ad9508aea0> in <module>()
----> 1 page = urllib2.urlopen(path)
      2 soup = bs(page, 'lxml')
      3 a = soup.find_all("a")
      4 path = re.search(pattern, str(a[2])).group(0)
      5 path

C:\users\alex\Anaconda2\lib\urllib2.pyc in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    152     else:
    153         opener = _opener
--> 154     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    155 
    156 def install_opener(opener):

C:\users\alex\Anaconda2\lib\urllib2.pyc in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    427             req = meth(req)
    428 
--> 429         response = self._open(req, data)
    430 
    431         # post-process response

C:\users\alex\Anaconda2\lib\urllib2.pyc in _open(self, req, data)
    450 
    451         return self._call_chain(self.handle_open, 'unknown',
--> 452                                 'unknown_open', req)
    453 
    454     def error(self, proto, *args):

C:\users\alex\Anaconda2\lib\urllib2.pyc in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    405             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
    406 
--> 407             result = func(*args)
    408             if result is not None:
    409                 return result

C:\users\alex\Anaconda2\lib\urllib2.pyc in unknown_open(self, req)
   1264     def unknown_open(self, req):
   1265         type = req.get_type()
-> 1266         raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
   1267 
   1268 def parse_keqv_list(l):

URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: "http>
```

Why urlopen does not recognize the url?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: in your url  you have `"` at the beginning and at the end - remove it.

Comment: BTW: if you use powerfull BeautifulSoup then you don't need `re`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.group(1)` when retrieving result of regex matching. `.group(0)` returns the whole matched string including quotes.

Answer (score 2):

The issue I guess is that you have extra quotes in you `path`

```
'"http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Montgomery.html"'
```

Trim the string using `strip()` as

```
path = path.strip('"')
page = urllib2.urlopen(path)
```

---

You can use BeautifulSoup to extract the src of from the anchor tags. You need not use regex for this purpose

**Example**

```
>>> html = """<a href="http://www.google.com">"""
>>> soup.find_all('a')[0]['href']
'http://www.google.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
path.strip('"')
```

out:

```
'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Montgomery.html'
```

the url is incorrect, just strip the `"` in the url or adjust your regex

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because you have `"` in url. Remove it.

But BeautifulSoup has own methods to get url - `a[2]['href']`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib2

# - first page -

path = "http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Fikret.html"

page = urllib2.urlopen(path)
soup = bs(page, 'lxml')

all_links = soup.find_all("a")

#for link in all_links:
#    print link['href']

print all_links[2]['href']

# - second page -

path = all_links[2]['href']

page = urllib2.urlopen(path)
soup = bs(page, 'lxml')

all_links = soup.find_all("a")

#for link in all_links:
#    print link['href']

print all_links[2]['href']
```

or shorter

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib2

def get_url(path):
    page = urllib2.urlopen(path)
    soup = bs(page, 'lxml')

    all_links = soup.find_all("a")

    #for link in all_links:
    #    print link['href']

    return all_links[2]['href']

# - first page -

path = "http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Fikret.html"

path = get_url(path)

print path

# - second page -

path = get_url(path)

print path
```